# Make OS X Server a wireless bridge without DHCP

Tags: macos, network, wifi, osx-server, internet-sharing

I have a Mac Mini running OS X Server 10.10 (Yosemite). It gets it's network connection over ethernet. I would like to bridge that connection through WiFi. That's easy enough with Internet Sharing, but then I end up with a new private network.

This question makes it clear that Internet Sharing cannot be used this way: [Internet sharing without DHCP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63675/internet-sharing-without-dhcp)

However, since this is OS X Server, is there a way I can manually configure things to have the same setup without using the Internet Sharing feature?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have another device handing out the DHCP leases. If so, try modifying the DHCP settings on the Ethernet Interface directly, and then turn on Internet Sharing. To do this:

System Preferences > Network, click the "Location" menu, and click "Edit Locations," name your new location, and click "Done". For Ethernet, click the "Configure IPv4 menu and select "Using BootP," click "Apply". In the left field, select "Wi-Fi," click the "Advanced" button, go to the "TCP/IP" tab and change "Configure IPv4 to "Using BootP" as well. Click "Apply," then go back to System Preferences and click "Sharing," and enable "Internet Sharing" in the left field. Set "Share your connection from:" to "Ethernet," and click the "Wi-Fi" box in the "To computers using:" field.